# Monitor and copy to and from multiple locations

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

Trying to automatically copy files from one PC (not on network) to a network location using a bridging PC with two network cards.

I have managed to put together this script from a previous post on the subject. This works great!

The issue I have is that I need to monitor and copy files from two locations on the PC to two separate locations on the bridging PC

**C:\Source → C:\Destination**

and

**C:\Source2 → C:\Destination2**

I tried running 2 PowerShell scripts with different sources and destinations however it wont allow the second to run while the first is running. The following error message occurs:

```
Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot subscribe to the specified event. A subscriber
with the source identifier 'FileCreated' already exists.
At ****\PowerShell\movePowerhell - Copy.ps1:8 char:14
+ ... onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileC ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.IO.FileSystemWatcher:FileSystemWatcher) [Register-ObjectEvent], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SUBSCRIBER_EXISTS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RegisterObjectEventCommand
```

I assume I need to monitor both locations and copy to both destinations in the same script?

I have tried creating a array with both sources and destinations and looping through the code twice but I get the same error as above.

```
$folder = "C:\Source"
$filter = "*.*"
requirements
$destination = "C:\Destination"
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action {
    $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Move-Item $path -Destination $destination -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-3.0#optional-parameters) (emphasis mine):

> **`-SourceIdentifier`**
>
> Specifies a name that you select for the subscription. ***The name that you select must be unique in the current session.*** The default value is the GUID that Windows PowerShell assigns.

The simplest way to avoid the issue is to not specify a source identifier. If you omit the parameter PowerShell will automatically set a GUID as the source identifier, which will avoid name collisions.